# How to get seleced values by jQRangeSlider

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to integrate jQRangeSlider into my jqplot applications, which means users can slide the x axis and decide the range of plots to be illustrated. However, I am having some difficulties of accessing the selected range. 
Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/vM844/223/) of my approach.

It seems like selected values are saved in the following `<divs>`

```
<div class="ui-rangeSlider-label-value">2010-02-11</div>
<div class="ui-rangeSlider-label-value">2011-02-11</div>
```

I tried to use

```
alert($(".ui-rangeSlider-label-value").val())
```

but got empty return. I appreciate if anyone could give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I found the method from the documents of jqrangeslider. Here is a quick example

```
var values = $("#slider").dateRangeSlider("values");
console.log(values .min + " " + values .max);
```